# json.filter() doesn't return any result without manually refreshing once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, parse-platform, back4app

I am making an expense tracker app using React Native and Back4App (Parse) as backend. I want to fetch all objects under class `Transactions` in the Parse database and filter them by `username`. The results are like these,

```
Array [
  Object {
    "amount": -350,
    "objectId": "hzXdXRj8jf",
    "type": "Expense",
    "username": "james",
  },
  Object {
    "amount": -200,
    "objectId": "r2uDmSZ666",
    "type": "Expense",
    "username": "james",
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 2000,
    "objectId": "FBEGubpwNn",
    "type": "Income",
    "username": "sheldon",
  },
  Object {
    "amount": -500,
    "objectId": "oYam0dUOxu",
    "type": "Expense",
    "username": "sheldon",
  },
]
```

Since, I am using `james` account, I want to see results with username `james`. This the code I use,

```
    const getCurrentUser = async () => {
        const user = await Parse.User.currentAsync()
        if(user !== null) {
            setUsername(user.get('username'))
        } else {
            Alert.alert("Error!", "Cannot fetch username")
        }
    }

    const readTransactions = async () => {
        setLoading(true)
        getCurrentUser()
        const parseQuery = new Parse.Query("Transactions")
        try {
            let results = await parseQuery.find()
            let json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results))
            var filteredJSON = json.filter(it => it.username === username)
            console.log(filteredJSON)
            setTransactions(filteredJSON)
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            return true
        } catch (error) {
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        }
    }

    const onRefresh = () => {
        setRefresh(true)
        readTransactions()
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        isFocused && readTransactions()
    }, [isFocused])
```

If I reload the app / open the app for first time, it doesn't fetch any results i.e. `console.log(filteredJSON)` returns `Array []`.
But upon manually refreshing the flatlist, it returns the correct results

```
Array []
Array [
  Object {
    "amount": -350,
    "objectId": "hzXdXRj8jf",
    "type": "Expense",
    "username": "james",
  },
  Object {
    "amount": -200,
    "objectId": "r2uDmSZ666",
    "type": "Expense",
    "username": "james",
  },
]
```

So, the problem is `filteredJSON` doesn't return any result upon restarting the app but it returns the correct results on refreshing once. But obviously, I want to return the correct data when the user opens the app without manually refreshing.

Even if I use `parseQuery.contains('username', username)` without using any json filter, the problem still persists.

(If I do `setTransactions(json)` it fetches the correct results at first chance without any refreshing, but I don't want to do that since it will return all data of various users under `Transactions` class.)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `getCurrentUser` request hasn't resolved by the time you run your first filter. This causes an empty result, since none of the transactions have an `undefined` username.

One solution would be to only run `readTransactions` if you have the username. You could do this in your useEffect:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        isFocused && username && readTransactions()
    }, [isFocused, username])
```

You did well in finding the line that the issue appears on. In the future, once you find that line, you can try logging out each part of it - you would have seen that `username` was undefined.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I understand what you are trying to say and I tried your solution, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Can you share what you get from the logs at each step of readTransactions?

Comment: Upon opening, `console.log('username: ${username}')` doesn't show anything, neither does `console.log(filteredJSON)`, but after refreshing once they show up correctly.

Comment: By "doesn't show anything", do you mean the console.log is never called, or that the two logs show that the variables are undefined?

Comment: it shows `undefined` for username and `Array[]` for filteredJSON

Comment: Can you show your useEffect code? If username is undefined, it means that readTransactions is running when it shouldn't. It should only run when username is defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter currentUser.

Before, You should set acl these records.

You can do it **new ACL()** and **set req.User.id** while saving data...

And if you run any query, automatically currentUser filtered these queries, so returned related to these user's transactions.

But If you don`t want to this way. If you want to find every users transactions.

You can filter this way.

```
const result = [Your query.]
let cUserData=[]

result.forEach(x=>x.get('user').id ===currentUser.id? cUserData.push(x):null)
```

I hope this is helpful.